# js code displays as text on hover

Tags: javascript

There's a hidden block with some javascript code inside `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag. 
When I hover on the div I see this code as text. If I move js code outside the hidden block, the code is invisible. Why this happens?

You can check my demo here: http://goo.gl/XVlhXq Just hover on any product image.

Bug screen: http://goo.gl/Qvu7Hr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that CSS rule

```
.car-item:hover .hide * {
    display: block;
}
```

Which also targets `script` tags.

Either do not add scripts inside the page markup (e.g. put it at the end of the body) or add a less specific CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
script {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got

```
.car-item .hide {
      display:block;
}
```

overriding the

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

as it has more classes defined and therefore higher level by [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

You can workaround this by either

- removing display:block from .car-item .hide,
- adding !important flag like

  .hide {
      display:none;!important
  }
- adding a couple classes to it, which is awful, like

  .car-item .hide * {
      display:none;
  }

Also, this is unrelated, but you have

```
<div class="rating">
```

inside your

```
<div class="hide">
```

which doesnt sound right. Maybe that's a case, because having "height: 15px;" isn't quite "hiding".